# getting error Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '(UIControl.State) -> UIImage?' and 'UIImage?'

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

```
let isMute = self.buttonMute.image == UIImage(named: "mute")
self.buttonMute.image = isMute ? UIImage(named: "volume") : UIImage(named: "mute")
self.baseViewModel.mute(!isMute)

print("button mute")
```

Comment: What is `buttonMute`, is it a `UIButton`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare button current image with assets image then use **currentImage** property like as below.

```
let isMute = buttonMute.currentImage == UIImage(named: "mute")
```

Answer (score 1):

If `buttonMute` is of type `UIButton` (and it is because you're getting error with `UIControl.state`), you have to get current image like this

```
self.buttonMute.image(for: .normal)
```

then when you need to set new image for your button you have to call `setImage` with your image as parameter

```
let image = isMute ? UIImage(named: "volume") : UIImage(named: "mute")
self.buttonMute.setImage(image, for: .normal)
```